# Golang : interface to swap two numbers

Tags: go

I want to swap two numbers using interface but the interface concept is so confusing to me.

http://play.golang.org/p/qhwyxMRj-c

This is the code and playground.  How do I use interface and swap two input numbers? Do I need to define two structures?

```
type num struct {
    value interface{}
}

type numbers struct {
    b *num
    c *num
}

func (a *num) SwapNum(var1, var2 interface{}) {
    var a num

    temp := var1
    var1 = var2
    var2 = temp
}

func main() {
    a := 1
    b := 2
    c := 3.5
    d := 5.5

    SwapNum(a, b)
    fmt.Println(a, b) // 2 1
    SwapNum(c, d)
    fmt.Println(c, d) // 5.5 3.5
}
```

Comment: I guess you know that you can swap number like this: `a,b = b, a`, and this is just for learning interfaces, right?

Comment: oh yeah. Just trying out interface with the simplest example that I can come up with.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, the `interface{}` type is simply a type which accepts all values as it is an interface with an empty method set and every type can satisfy that. `int` for example does not have any methods, neither does `interface{}`.

For a method which swaps the values of two variables you first need to make sure these variables are actually modifiable. Values passed to a function are always copied (except reference types like slices and maps but that is not our concern at the moment). You can achieve modifiable parameter by using a pointer to the variable.

So with that knowledge you can go on and define `SwapNum` like this:

```
func SwapNum(a interface{}, b interface{})
```

Now `SwapNum` is a function that accepts two parameters of any type.
You can't write

```
func SwapNum(a *interface{}, b *interface{})
```

as this would only accept parameters of type `*interface{}` and not just any type.
(Try it for yourself [here](http://play.golang.org/p/fpXsnvqIpP)).

So we have a signature, the only thing left is swapping the values.

```
func SwapNum(a interface{}, b interface{}) {
    *a, *b = *b, *a
}
```

No, this will **not** work that way. By using `interface{}` we must do runtime type assertions to check whether we're doing the right thing or not. So the code must be expanded using the `reflect` package. [This article](http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection) might get you started if you don't know about reflection.

Basically we will need this function:

```
func SwapNum(a interface{}, b interface{}) {
    ra := reflect.ValueOf(a).Elem()
    rb := reflect.ValueOf(b).Elem()
    tmp := ra.Interface()

    ra.Set(rb)
    rb.Set(reflect.ValueOf(tmp))
}
```

This code makes a reflection of `a` and `b` using [`reflect.ValueOf()`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#ValueOf) so that we can 
inspect it. In the same line we're assuming that we've got pointer values and dereference 
them by calling [`.Elem()`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Elem) on them.

This basically translates to `ra := *a` and `rb := *b`.
After that, we're making a copy of `*a` by requesting the value using [`.Interface()`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface) 
and assigning it (effectively making a copy).

Finally, we set the value of `a` to `b` with `[ra.Set(rb)`][5](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Set), which translates to `*a = *b`
and then assigning `b` to `a`, which we stored in the temp. variable before. For this, 
we need to convert `tmp` back to a reflection of itself so that `rb.Set()` can be used
(it takes a `reflect.Value` as parameter).

#### Can we do better?

Yes! We can make the code more type safe, or better, make the definition of `Swap` type safe
by using [`reflect.MakeFunc`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#MakeFunc). In the doc (follow the link) is an example which is very 
like what you're trying. Essentially you can fill a function prototype with content 
by using reflection. As you supplied the prototype (the signature) of the function the 
compiler can check the types, which it can't when the value is reduced to `interface{}`.

Example usage:

```
var intSwap func(*int, *int)
a,b := 1, 0
makeSwap(&intSwap)
intSwap(&a, &b)
// a is now 0, b is now 1
```

The code behind this:

```
swap := func(in []reflect.Value) []reflect.Value {
    ra := in[0].Elem()
    rb := in[1].Elem()
    tmp := ra.Interface()

    ra.Set(rb)
    rb.Set(reflect.ValueOf(tmp))

    return nil
}

makeSwap := func(fptr interface{}) {
    fn := reflect.ValueOf(fptr).Elem()
    v := reflect.MakeFunc(fn.Type(), swap)
    fn.Set(v)
}
```

The code of `swap` is basically the same as that of `SwapNum`. `makeSwap` is the same
as the one used in the docs where it is explained pretty well.

**Disclaimer:** The code above makes a lot of assumptions about what is given and
what the values look like. Normally you need to check, for example, that the given
values to `SwapNum` actually are pointer values and so forth. I left that out for
reasons of clarity.

Comment: _"Values passed to a function are always copied (except reference types like slices and maps but that is not our concert at the moment)"_. Aren't slices and maps values always copied also? You can modify them because internally they point to a data structure, but my understanding was that their values are copied.

Comment: It works thanks, but the first example. How come I have to pass pointers even if interface does not say anything about pointers?

Comment: @KeenanERNLDKNF `interface{}` only says that you can pass a variable of every type but all other rules still apply, for example that values are copied. Therefore you need to pass a pointer to be able to modify the values.

Comment: @aromero Technically yes, but they're just a descriptor so it doesn't seem that they're copied as they still reference the same underlying array. 'A slice is a descriptor for a contiguous segment of an array and provides access to a numbered sequence of elements from that array.' ([spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) and [internals[(http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals))